while try to create autoscaling in AWS getting error im missing something out
Getting error while creating autoscaling using launch template.
Auto Scaling group could not be created
The InstanceRequirements in MixedInstancesPolicy.Overrides[0] does not match any instance type in the availability zones us-west-1b
Getting error while creating autoscaling using launch template.
Auto Scaling group could not be created
The InstanceRequirements in MixedInstancesPolicy.Overrides[0] does not match any instance type in the availability zones us-west-1b
